# Why is my pixel art scaling wrong on other resolutions?

Tags: unity-game-engine, screen, pixel, scaling, resolution

My pixel art assets all have a ppu of 32 and i have applied that to them all.

On 1920x1080, the resolution is fine, but most other resolutions the sprites pixels are squashed and stretched. I also have set the correct camera size using vertical resolution / PPU / 2). I have also used other formulas and they all give me the same camera size so i'm sure that's not the issue.

I have two moniters, one at 1920x1080, and one at 1360x768, and that moniter is where it scales wrong. Is there a way i can keep the pixels scaling the same across all resolutions? I have tried the pixel perfect camera and this doesn't fix my issue either.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0tUt.jpg Here is a sample of both resolutions, if you open them in a new tab and zoom in on the sprite you can see how tey get distorted in the 1360x768 screen.

Answer (score 0):

Filter mode should be `Point` and compression `None`. If this doesn't fix it, then you should use Pixel Perfect camera. It will help you with the animations to be pixel perfect as well.

Window -> Package Manager -> Advanced -> Show preview packages -> 2D Pixel Perfect -> Instlal. Then you just add Pixel Perfect Camera component to your Camera.

Comment: both filter mode and compression are already set to that. I also tried using the pixel perfect asset and that didn't fix my issue.

Comment: Sad to hear that you've already tried the things I mentioned. You should make some research about creating a custom script that will manage your assets on different resolutions. But I think that the Pixel Perfect Camera has a PPU management and it will fix artifacts in your pixel assets. You have to research the pixel perfect camera more